# Show user location on Google Maps (not from IP) through Wi-Fi

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, location, wifi

for a team project, I have been trying to get and show user location on Google Maps but it is only showing the location based on the IP address and it is not right because our government takes internet from another country.

Anyways, is there any way to do that like in mobile phones? For example through Wi-Fi for accuracy?

*btw, it is a both desktop web site and mobile web site project, means the same project should work on both.*

Comment: update: I just tested with my friends, we put our mobile phones in airplane phone so no cellular network and gps was on. onyl the wi-fi is on. and tried to locate ourselves and it was successfull.

Comment: So this proves that it is possible. Im still looking for a way to do it though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

After all, I discovered that it depends on the browser you use. It does not make sense to me but if I use Chrome then it shows my location (accurate) and if I use IE it shows my IP location which is not my current location.

Why browsers do that differently? I didnt understand it but using Chrome solved it :)